# Android Studio 2.0 debug build problems

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-2.0

Several days ago I updated my Android studio to 2.0 version and now I have several problems with it.

1. After building my application which was in total about 5MB (before updating) it turned out that now the app takes 5MB just for app, 11MB data, and 35MB cache. Why?
2. The app loads about 15 seconds on the first run and generates the following line for about 100 times - "04-21 11:48:05.206 12505-12505/com.dineoutmobile.dineout I/art: override thread count:-j2".
3. A complete build takes about 1 minute, but it used to be only about 10 seconds.

Here are my dependencies:

dependencies {

```
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.1'
compile 'com.pkmmte.view:circularimageview:1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.2.1'
compile 'com.githang:viewpagerindicator:2.4.2@aar'
```

}

I use only 1KB SQLite database which has only one table and I don't insert anything in it during run-time.

Is there some problem with Android studio or is it something wrong with my project?

Comment: Did Android-Studio use "instant Run" on the first builds? Maybe you just experienced exceptionally short build times at first and it switched to "normal" long builds.

Comment: Now I use "Instant Run", but before updating Android Studio there was no such feature and the initial build took much faster.

Comment: Don't use ```compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'``` , it will take your project build very hard, instead of specifying only the specific Google Play services APIs your app uses , refer : https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup#add_google_play_services_to_your_project

Comment: Do you have  multiDexEnabled set to true?

Answer (score 1):

Try [this](https://xrubio.com/2016/02/problems-with-instant-run-android-studio-2-0-beta-4-and-retrofit/).

Please do not click --> Enable Instant Run to hot swap code/resource changed on deploy (default enabled)

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem as you. It seems to be a problem with the Android Studio version. When I tried using Android Studio version 1.5.1 the startup time was back to normal. I'm not sure why this is happening, and for some reason the two Android Studio versions seem to create different apk-files?

Answer (score 0):

After updated gradle to 2.1 version, i don't have this problem anymore. Have you tried make update?

Comment: Yes, but the app still shows a lot of " I/art: override thread count:-j2".
After changing to gradle version 2.1 the number decreased a little bit, but it still lags on first run and writes the line " I/art: override thread count:-j2". for about 20 times...